# What's the semantic field of 由?

Tags: etymology

[image]

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary), p 1180.

What notions underlie or connect all these [ostensibly unrelated different senses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24102)? *Please be sure to cover all senses in all your answer*. These senses' unlikeness should be obvious! First, their Syntactic Categories differ. Second, "be up to sb; rest with sb" obviously differs from "follow; obey". Third, "from" obviously differs from "via", and they both obviously differ from "by; through".

[image]

*Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 906.

Comment: you can see this  <http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/15828.html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the entry of 由 in GU Yankui 谷衍奎 ed., Hanzi yuanliu zidian 汉字源流字典 (Beijing: Yuwen 语文出版社, 2008).

[image: GU Yankui 谷衍奎 ed., Hanzi yuanliu zidian 汉字源流字典 (Beijing: Yuwen 语文出版社, 2008), p. 166]